# How to animate a character with the new Asset Browser?

Tags: linked-data, instances

Despite it still being in development, the new Asset Browser in v2.92 is a game changer. I'm wondering if it's currently possible to have a collection containing a rigged character and animate that character's rig after adding it via this asset browser? If this is currently possible, how might I do this?

At the very least, is it possible to assign any animation to the rig?